# Prettier config for intellij settings

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, prettier

On one of our frontend (react) repos we have code written for the past 2 years styled with default IntelliJ code-settings
We would like to start using Prettier and not be coupled with 1 IDE, we see 2 options:

1. Run prettier on all legacy code and configure IntelliJ with prettier for code-style
2. Configure prettier to the same settings IntelliJ has as default

We would prefer to go with option #2 since we want to keep a clean git history, any suggestions on how to configure Prettier with IntelliJ settings, and if that sounds like the right thing to do as Prettier is opinionated about some code-styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prettier is opinionated formatter with a very limited set of [configuration options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), and its team is not going to accept any requests for adding new options, see https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html. So Prettier can hardly be configured to produce the same output as IDEA formatter.

I'd suggest using Prettier as a formatter for your code, it can be set up as a [default formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prettier.html#ws_prettier_default_formatter) for IDEA

Comment: We will go with the suggested answer of running prettier on legacy code, and will try to tidy our github history as suggested here:
https://medium.com/codex/how-to-introduce-a-code-formatter-without-messing-up-git-history-4a16bd074c10